# Disable Foreign Key Exposure in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-data, entity-framework-4

When I originally created a Dynamic Data project I told it to expose the foreign keys, but now I can't make mappings between two entities b/c of the foreign keys. When I click on mapping details while focused on my association I receive the message:

> Mappings are not allow for an association over exposed foreign keys.

So I'd like to disable the exposure of the foreign keys but am unsure how to do this without creating a new Entity Model from scratch. I'm not far along - so that wouldn't be hard, but I imagine there must be a programmatic switch for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just delete the foreign key property from the entity .
then delete the association --> add new association between the entities and uncheck the :

"add foreign key properties to..X"